# How advanced is the study of mathematically determining computational power comsumption?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, power-consumption

I was thinking about how effective it would be to calculate the number of CPU instructions a section of code would have and then trying to estimate the energy cost for a program.

But I was curious if there were more elegant ways of going about this?

Comment: In which model? A former colleague investigated this and quickly found reality mostly intractable: the power consumption of real CPUs is not "context-free"/additive since instructions take different amount of energies depending on recent history, in particular (but not only) because components are turned on and off following some heuristic or another.

Comment: The easiest way is to compile the program and run it. Otherwise these estimates are very difficult, since the compiler performs many optimizations, and the execution model of modern CPU is extremely complicated.

Comment: with increasing emphasis on cpu energy consumption minimization/ efficiency, this is increasingly done by cpu designers who yes, have some very sophisticated analysis, although it tends to be cpu-specific, can possibly find/ dig up refs for that. theres also a new style of hardware & corresponding research that sacrifices some accuracy in favor of decreased energy consumption.

Comment: If anything one could determine a max energy use as a worse-case ceiling. If every lookup was a miss and if no prediction was preformed, etc.